# Microsoft wire keyboard 400 doesn't support russian unicode

Tags: keyboard

I have a question about the Microsoft keyboard. It has Russian letters on it, but when I try to use KDWIN for example to type in Russian Unicode, the keyboard instead of that types only according with the position of Russian keys n its keys.

For example if it use KDWIN properly than the English letter 'a' will also be Russian 'a' symbol, the symbol 's' will be Russian 'с' and so on.

Instead that the 'a' is 'ф'. I have also installed all Russian fonts so they aren't the problem.

Can anyone guide how to resolve this problem?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you having such problems with any other keyboard? I don't think that the problem is with the keyboard. Keyboards generate special signals called scancodes when a button is pressed and it's up to computer to decode them. Internally keyboards with same physical layout will almost always produce same scancodes for each button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Check KDWIN settings. When you open the KDWIN window, you should on the left have two small Russian flags one above another.

You need to click on the top Russian flag. It has a yellow circle on it. This will switch the program to Russian Phonetic Unicode.

This one is with the Russian Phonetic Unicode:
`явертыуиопшщасдфгхйкл;'э`
and this one is with Russian typewriter:
`йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэ\`

From what I can see, you're getting the bottom one and you want the top one.